# Embedding a compact manifold in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

I have an attempt at solving the following problem. This is not so much a question asking for a solution in general, but more on how to complete my own.

> Let $M^n$ be a compact smooth manifold. Show that there exists an embedding of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N$.

(Recall that an embedding of smooth manifolds is a topological embedding such that each differential is injective.)

**My attempt:**

Since $M$ is compact, we can cover it by finitely many coordinate neighbourhoods $U_i$ for $i=1,\dotsc,k$, where $\varphi_i : U_i \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are the corresponding charts. Choose a subordinate (smooth) partition of unity $\psi_i : M \to \mathbb{R}$. Then the functions
$$ f_i := \psi_i \cdot \varphi_i$$
are smooth, where we interpret $\varphi$ as being zero outside of the support of $\psi$. Now define
$$ F : M \to \mathbb{R}^{n\cdot k + k} : x\mapsto (f_1(x),\dotsc,f_k(x),\psi_1(x),\dotsc,\psi_k(x)).$$
My hope was that $F$ is an embedding of smooth manifolds. For this, we verify:

- *Injectivity*. This is why the $\psi$'s were stuck at the end of the map. If all the $\psi(x)$'s are the same, then all the $\varphi(x)$'s are the same, but these are local diffeomorphisms, in particular bijections.
- *Smoothness*. Trivial.
- *Topological embedding*. Immediate since $M$ is compact and $F$ is injective and continuous.
- *Injective differentials*. This is my issue.

Are all the differentials injective for $F$ as defined above? Or would we need more assumptions on the covering or of the partition of unity for this to work (or for this to work more easily)?

Comment: This is whitney lemma

Comment: @TsemoAristide Which lemma are you referring to? If it's just about embedding a compact manifold in $\mathbb{R}^N$, then like I stated, that's not the point of me raising this question.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem

Comment: @TsemoAristide Thanks for the reference, but again, I am asking this question about my own attempted solution, not a general proof.

Comment: Read the proof of Whitney's theorem, it starts like your idea, then by using sard lemma it can be shown that $M$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R} ^{2n+1}$ where $n$ is the dimension of $M$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide Right, I hadn't realised that the proof was so much like my attempt (at least, the way Lee does it). That basically answers it - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x \in M$ be such that $T_x F$ is not injective. Then there exists some nonzero $X \in T_x M$ such that $T_xF(X)=0$.

Let $i$ be such that $\psi_i(x)>0$, then $d_x \psi_i(X)=0$ (It is a component of $F$) and $T_x(\psi_i\phi_i)(X)=0$.
Now, since $d_x\psi_i(X)=0$, $0=T_x(\psi_i\phi_i)(X) = \psi_i(x)T_x\phi_i(X)$.

Thus, $T_x\phi_i(X)=0$, a contradiction.
So your differentials are injective.

Comment: How does it follow that $\nabla_x \psi_i =0$? (And I’m presuming that by $\nabla \psi$ you mean the differential of $\psi$?)

Comment: Edited, I hope I answered your concern.

Comment: You did, yes :) Thank you!